# Adding images to an info window from a GeoJSON file? Google maps javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson, infowindow

Basically, I want to display an info window from a marker that can show several information from a GeoJSON file, such as date, hour and type of event (I can do all of this by now)... **but I also need a specific image for each marker info window**.

```
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {

  var myIMAGE = event.feature.getProperty("Image");
  var myDATE = event.feature.getProperty("Date");
  var myHOUR = event.feature.getProperty("Hour");     
  var myCATEGORY = event.feature.getProperty("Category");

  infowindow.setContent("<div style='width:150px; text-align: left;'>"+"<b>Category: </b>"+myCATEGORY +"<br>"+"<b>Date: </b>"+ myDATE +"<br>"+"<b>Hour: </b>"+myHOUR +"<br>" +"<b>Image:</b>" +"<br>" + "<img src= 'myIMAGEN' alt='Dale la Cara AC' >" + "</div>");
```

l know that the possible mistake is in:

```
+ "<img src= 'myIMAGE' alt='Dale la Cara AC'>"
```

This is my GeoJSON string:

```
{"id":"MPBA001","properties":{"Image":"http://storage.googleapis.com/ops_geojson/Flecker/Icons/Atoyac/Marcador_BasuraEnBarrancas.png","Latitude":19.0225448527012,"Category":"Agua","Date":"21/03","Hour":"21:00pm","ID":"MPBA001","Longitude":-98.1973242759704}, "type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-98.1973242759704,19.0225448527012]}}
```

Each info window has a different image within. Is there a way to call the link from my GeoJSON string to the 'src' value? So I can display this image in my info window.

Thanks!

Comment: A negative vote without a comment, this is not fair to someone new to SOF.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be:

```
+ "<img src= '" + myIMAGE + "' alt='Dale la Cara AC'>"
```

currently you set the `src` of the `<img/>` to the string `myIMAGE` and not the the value of the variable `myIMAGE`